# Sum operation on dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
    dict_connected_hosts = {

        {'10.0.0.2': [[12564.0, 6844.0, 632711.0, 56589,0, 4856,0], <ryu.controller.controller.Datapath object at 0x7f2b2008a7d0>, '10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.1', 2, datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 2, 24, 12, 301565)]}
        {'10.0.0.3': [[3193.0, 621482.0, 6412.0, 2146.0, 98542.0], <ryu.controller.controller.Datapath object at 0x7f2b2008a7d0>, '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.1', 3, datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 2, 24, 12, 302224)]
        {'10.0.0.7': [[4545.0, 51442.0, 325.0, 452.0, 3555.0], <ryu.controller.controller.Datapath object at 0x7f2b2008a7d0>, '10.0.0.7', '10.0.0.1', 3, datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 2, 24, 12, 302250)]

 }
```

how can I sum the first numbers of each list in the value field? In simple terms numbers

```
`12564.0 + 3193.0 + 4545.0`
```

thanks

Comment: Please edit the question and fix the syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have debugged your dictionary structure. The **relevant** part of it should be :

```
{
        '10.0.0.2': [[12564.0, 6844.0, 632711.0, 56589,0, 4856,0]],
        '10.0.0.3': [[3193.0, 621482.0, 6412.0, 2146.0, 98542.0]],
        '10.0.0.7': [[4545.0, 51442.0, 325.0, 452.0, 3555.0]]
}
```

**Note :** ignoring the other elements in the `values` as they are not relevant to the question (and they have errors I don't care to debug)

So, to get the sum of the `first numbers in the first list of each value`, you can do it by `list comprehension` :

```
#suppose `a` is the dictionary

print([val[0][0] for val in a.values()])
#[12564.0, 3193.0, 4545.0]

print(sum( [val[0][0] for val in a.values()] ))
#20302.0
```